# Extracting time series for best performing agents in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I apologise if this question is basic, but I've gone through the documentation and I am having trouble figuring out what the simple canonical way to deal with this problem is, although this is probably because I am very new to pandas.

I have a DataFrame `df` representing time series data (where time is measured by `step`s) for `score`s of a series of systems, parametrised by hyperparameters `paramA` and `paramB`.

A synthetic sample of the data is as follows:

```
| paramA | paramB | score | step |
----------------------------------
|   A    |    c   |   .8  |  10  |
|   B    |    e   |   .2  |  10  |
|   A    |    f   |   .1  |  40  |
|   C    |    c   |   .9  |  10  |
|   B    |    e   |   .3  |  20  |
|   B    |    c   |   .3  |  10  |
|   A    |    c   |   .7  |  20  |
|   C    |    f   |   .4  |  60  |
|  ...   |   ...  |  ...  |  ... |
```

I want do the following things:

#### 1. Find top scoring models

For each model (i.e. for each possible pair of hyperparameters in the dataset), find the row with the top score. I currently am doing this with:

```
df.groupby([df.paramA, df.paramB]).score.max()
```

#### 2. Extract time series for top scorers

I now want to get the time series for the top `k` models I obtained maxima for in the previous step.

Obviously I can manually look up the top scoring models in the previous step, get `k` dataframes using `k` separate queries, but this feels slow and inelegant. I'm assuming there's a smarter way of doing this.

Again, apologies if this is very simple, but any assistance in solving this problem the clever way, rather than the brute-force way I currently have in mind, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To answer question one, first create a unique set of models, initialize an empty dictionary using the parameter set of each model, and then fill the dictionary with the index of the maximum score:

```
pairs = pd.Series(zip(df.paramA, df.paramB)).unique()
models = {(A, B): None for A, B in pairs}
for A, B in pairs:
    models[(A, B)] = df.loc[((df.paramA == A) & (df.paramB == B)), 'score'].idxmax()

>>> models
{('A', 'c'): 0,
 ('A', 'f'): 2,
 ('B', 'c'): 5,
 ('B', 'e'): 4,
 ('C', 'c'): 3,
 ('C', 'f'): 7}
```

To get the top `k` models with the highest scores:

```
k = 5  # Top number of models to return
m = [(v, k_) for k_, v in models.iteritems()]
m.sort(reverse=True)
top_models = [model[1] for model in m[:k]]
>>> top_models
[('C', 'f'), ('B', 'c'), ('B', 'e'), ('C', 'c'), ('A', 'f')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the comment. I've removed the plotting question, but the two other parts of the question are linked, so it might not work to treat them separately.